# Swagger API key? Do i need to insert my API key to make a gen a client? Im trying to use python to interact with the api, but i need to gen the code

Tags: api, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator, autorest

I have a key, but I have no idea where to put it. In the swagger file that will generate the python code? I'm new to APIs. I have inserted the key into the ***"header":[]*** and ***"query":[]*** as well, but to no avail, nothing works when I gen the code. Using auto-rest, I get an error: Error: ***Azure Key security scheme should be of in 'header' but was 'query'***